# AES Encryption / Decryption Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am facing error in AES encrypt and decrypt

I am using [these CODE](https://github.com/Pakhee/Cross-platform-AES-encryption/tree/master/iOS)

And using in my viewcontroller like this // read show error comment in code
Please fix how to use it?

```
#import "CryptLib.h"
#import "NSData+Base64.h"


-(NSData *)encryption:(NSString*)myString
{



     NSString * secret = @"This the sample text has to be encrypted"; // this is the text that you want to encrypt.

     NSString * key = @"shared secret"; //secret key for encryption. To make encryption stronger, we will not use this key directly. We'll first hash the key next step and then use it.

     key = [[CryptLib alloc] sha256:key length:32]; //this is very important, 32 bytes = 256 bit
    NSString * iv =   [[[[CryptLib alloc] generateRandomIV:11]  base64EncodingWithLineLength:0] substringToIndex:16]; //Here we are generating random initialization vector (iv). Length of this vector = 16 bytes = 128 bits  //SHOWS ERROR HERE

    // Now that we have input text, hashed key and random IV, we are all set for encryption:
     NSData * encryptedData = [[CryptLib alloc] encrypt:[secret dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] key:key iv:iv];

     NSLog(@"encrypted data:: %@",[encryptedData  base64EncodingWithLineLength:0]); //print the encrypted text  //SHOWS ERROR HERE
    // Encryption = [plainText + secretKey + randomIV] = Cyphertext

    return encryptedData;
}
```

Comment: Do not use CryptLib, it is full of errors, poor design and 30 open issues. For a good, complete and secure solution use [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-objc).

Comment: ok let me check thanks